# Load Testing on .Net Web Services

Tags: .net, web-services, load-testing

I am having web services in my .Net web application. I am also using the unit testing framework in visual studio for unit testing these web services.

Is there a way in which i can load test these web services using the test methods i have created or is there some other way i can load test them.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio has a load testing component that can utilize unit tests.  I'm not sure of the cost - I think it is included with the ultimate edition and/or the team test editions of VS. If that is out of your budget, search for "web load testing software" - you'll find a variety of testing tools that can help you. Most of them can handle web services.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LoadUI](http://loadui.org/) tool and it can be integrated with the SOAPUI tool as well.

Answer (score 0):

For WCF web service you can use the Web Performance Test from VS2010, maybe this would help: http://zoraradosavlevici.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/how-to-test-wcf-asmx-web-services/